# Set cube origin (0, 0, 0) to its first first instead of cube center

Tags: mesh, origin

When I add a cube, it's centered by default, instead I'd like to set its position x,y,z according to its begining point.

Like in the image below:
[image]

But I need to set lcoation x,y,z to 1 to get this result instead of origin point 0,0,0 and when when I scale it, it's scaling from the center, not from origin (0,0,0).

How to change this behavior ?

Comment: what do u mean by "beginning point"?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I would like to add many cubes and position them from first edge's first point at (0,0,0), not from their center.

Comment: can u post a screenshot showing what u mean by "first edge's first point"?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I rephrased my question, I'm sorry I don't have the words to express it clearly, I hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: press `Ctrl+A` in object mode then Apply Transformation.

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself doing this a lot, there is an Add-on "Set Origin in Edit Mode", which you can download [HERE](https://github.com/ChrisCrossCrash/SetOriginInEditMode)

With this, you can simply right-click on a vertex to set it as the origin.
(Make sure you download the .py file in RAW mode and then install via Edit>Preferences>Add-ons>Install...)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aside from their side and default location/alignment, you can't change how the `Add Object` tools will make the objects, including their origins. What you can do, is add a cube, set their origin where you need it to be, and then duplicate that cube.

#### Edit origin

There are several ways to change an objects origin, but for your specific need, the simplest might be to go in Edit Mode, select the vertex where you want the origin to be. Then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> → `3D cursor to selected`.

Switch back to object mode, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> → `Origin to 3D cursor`.

Another way is, first enable the option `Affect Only Origins` in the top right `Options` popover:

[image: options popover]

Then set your snapping to vertex:

[image: snapping to vertex]

Then select your cube, press <kbd>G</kbd> to move your cube's origin, hold down <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> to enable the snapping, move your cursor to the vertex you want to move your origin to, and validate by <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> or <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>.

Don't forget to disable `Affect Only Origins` after you're done.